# Filter data from deep json child

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

the JSON below is taken from other post. My issue is I know the id and I want to find out where is it located. Eg, I got ID **19006** and I want to get **Folder2**. How am I going to do this.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "",
        "childFolders": [{
            "id": 19002,
            "name": "Locker",
            "childFolders": [{
                "id": 19003,
                "name": "Folder1",
                "childFolders": [],
                "childComponents": [{
                    "id": 19005,
                    "name": "route1",
                    "state": "STOPPED",
                    "type": "ROUTE"
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 19004,
                "name": "Folder2",
                "childFolders": [],
                "childComponents": [{
                    "id": 19008,
                    "name": "comm1",
                    "state": "STOPPED",
                    "type": "COMMUNICATION_POINT"
                }, {
                    "id": 19006,
                    "name": "route2",
                    "state": "STOPPED",
                    "type": "ROUTE"
                }, {
                    "id": 19007,
                    "name": "route3",
                    "state": "STOPPED",
                    "type": "ROUTE"
                }]
            }],
            "childComponents": []
        }],
        "childComponents": []
    },
    "error": null
}
```

Comment: recursivelly reading the data tree (that isn't a code piece ) :P

Comment: My bad , should specify more clear XD btw can this be achieve using linq?

Comment: My answer below. Rmember check ansswer as ok if You like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write code now it is like this:

```
         var json = GetJsonString();
        
        var model = GetJsonModel(json);

         var folderName = GetName(model.data, 19006);
```

I chekced and code is correct. folderName is Folder2

[image]

And the recursive code:

```
 private string GetName(Data data, int searchValue)
    {
        var folderName = data.name;

        foreach (var item in data.childComponents)
        {
            if (item.id == searchValue)
            {
                return folderName;
            }
        }

        if (data.childFolders.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in data.childFolders)
            {
                var folderName1 = GetName(item, searchValue);

                if (folderName1 != null)
                {
                    return folderName1;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Your model is like this:

[image]

EDIT:

I parse Json like this.

```
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourJson>(test);
```

Comment: nice one mate, i try to modify abit and see it works, thanks a lot

Comment: Super. But remember please mark answer as  accept.

Comment: Hi bro, how do you parse the json data? I have issue on this because I am using asp.net and cannot use Newton Json lib. I able to parse this json data and get the outmost layer data which is id , name. Do you have any idea how to use deserialize to go into second layer?

Comment: I parse Json like this - i edited an answer